# Complex Continuity

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Is the function $f$, defined by

$$ f(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2+iz+1} & \text{ if } z \not \in \{-i\}\\
0 & \text{ if } z = -i
 \end{cases}$$

continuous at $−i$? Explain your answer.

Comment: Have you tried factoring the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Factor the denominator and numerator and cancel the factors common.

Comment: let z = -i, you will get 2z^2+iz+1=0 so it isn't analytic where z = -i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:$$f(z)=\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2+iz+1}=\frac{(z+i)^2}{(z+i)(2z-i)}=\frac{z+i}{2z-i},\quad\forall z\ne -i$$

Comment: but are you not just stating the function?? how does that show continuity???

Comment: @SamHarper Well, what's the definition of continuity then?

Comment: Suppose that the function f is defined in a set S ⊆ C, and that z0 ∈ S. We say that f is continuous at z0 if limz→z0 f(z) = f(z0); that is, the limit exists and is equal to f(z0). We say that f is continuous in S if it is continuous at all points of S.

Comment: so because the limit doesnt exists its not continuous!!!! THANKS

Comment: This is incorrect, the limit does exist, and it is equal to $f(z_0)$ therefore it is continuous

Comment: @THISISIT453 yes you're right. My mistake.

Comment: @SamHarper no it's wrong, the limit does exist. :)